# 301 Permanent Redirect to another Domain

Tags: iis, iis-7

I want to Redirect the old domain to new domain and without having different resources for each is it possible to use the same resource in IIS for both domains? Any suggestions please let me know

Answer (score 1):

**IF** I understand you correctly you want www.old.com to go to www.new.com. You should be able to put this in your `web.config` file of the old site.

```
<system.webServer>
<httpRedirect enabled=”true” destination=”http://www.my-new-site.com” httpResponseStatus=”Permanent” />
</system.webServer>
```

You can manually do it in IIS. Here are some steps.

1. Open IIS Manager and locate the website under sites
2. Important! Verify that it shows the correct website name at the top of the
   screen
3. Under the IIS section open “HTTP Redirect”
4. Put a check in “Redirect requests to this destination” and type in the new URL
5. Change the status code to “Permanent 301″
6. Click Apply (this results in an HTTP status code of: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently)

Comment: Thanks,Pjack your answer is resonable but other than scripting can i have any suggestions from you to do it manually in iis

Comment: ya Pjack its fine i tried it but it is effecting other sites so i am searching for other ways

Comment: Which one did you try? The first method or the manual method in IIS? If you do the updated answer and make sure you **only** select the website you want it should work. Note step 2 above.